# How to get original raw CSV row from file

Tags: python, csv

For example I have a CSV file like this:

```
a,b,c
a1,b1,c1
```

I want to get parsed data and the original raw CSV line. For example:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    # getting original raw csv line
    print(row)
    print(origin_row)
    # should print something like this:
    # ["a", "b", "c"]
    # a,b,c
```

CSV data could contain any possible data.
I need this to store parsed lines and raw lines for verification / validation / etc. I need to have parsed data and raw data per each row / entity.

Comment: Can the values contain new-lines `\n`? If yes, what should be the result then?

Comment: What are you trying to validate/verify, the csv parser itself? Also, please edit your question and include a mockup of the Python-ish data structure you want to get, based on the two-line sample CSV you shared.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, yes , it could contains quoted newline.

Comment: @ZachYoung, added an example to the question. No matter what I want to validate, I need to have parsed data and raw data per each row/entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't really well-defined, because you can't know how many lines of raw data corresponds to one CSV row when it could contain literal newlines until you have actually parsed it; but you seem to assume it can be represented as one line.

Here is a tortured sketch which uses two open file handles to separately read in the raw data after parsing.

```
import csv

def rawcsv(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as csvdata, open(
            filename, "rb") as rawdata:
        reader = csv.reader(csvdata)
        prev = 0
        for row in reader:
            # Where is the file pointer now?
            pos = reader.line_num
            # Read the same amount of rawdata
            raw = b"".join([rawdata.readline() for _ in range(pos - prev)])
            prev = pos
            yield raw, row

for raw, row in rawcsv("some.csv"):
    print(f"Raw: {raw}")
    print(f"Row: {row}")
```

(You need to keep this in a function for `yield` to make sense.)

Notice that `raw` will be a `bytes` object.

Demo: https://ideone.com/iqBQf0

My original sketch attempted to use `csvdata.tell()` but you can't because Python apparently loses the file pointer position when something calls `next()` on it, which `csv.reader` apparently does internally. Fortunately, it also provides `line_num`, which is sufficient for this code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

But this won't work if the values can contain newlines - so one CSV row is on multiple rows in the file.

```py
import csv
from itertools import tee

with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    f1, f2 = tee(f)
    for row, original_row in zip(csv.reader(f1), f2):
        # getting origin raw csv line
        print(row, original_row)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] a,b,c

['a1', 'b1', 'c1'] a1,b1,c1
```

Comment: This works for the simple sample CSV that OP shared, but will break with quoted linebreaks.